# How to detect repeating "sequences of words" across too many texts?

Tags: text, nlp, approximation, probabilistic-programming

The problem is to detect repeating sequences of words across big number of text pieces. It is an approximation and efficiency problem, since the data I want to work with is huge. I want the assign numbers to texts while indexing texts, if they have matching parts with the texts which are already indexed.

For example, if a TextB which I am indexing now has a matching part with 2 other texts in the database. I want to assign a number to it ,p1.
If that matching part would be longer then I want it to assign p2 (p2>p1).
If TextB has matching part with only 1 other text then it should give p3 (p3 < p1).
These two parameters(length of the sequence, size of the matching group) would have maximum values, meaning after these max values have been surpassed, the number being assigned stops increasing.

I can think of a way to do this in brute force, but I need efficieny. My boss directed me to learn about NLP and search solutions there and I am planing to follow through this [stanford video lectures](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLoROMvodv4rOhcuXMZkNm7j3fVwBBY42z).

But I am having doubts about if that is the right way to approach so I wanted to ask your opinion.

Example:
Text 1:"I want to become an artist and travel the world."
Text 2:"I want to become a musician."
Text 3:"travel the world."
Text 4:"She wants to travel the world."

Having these texts I want to have a data looks like this:
-"I want to become" , 2 instances , [1,2]
-"travel the world" , 3 instances , [1,3,4]

After having this data, finally, I wanna do this procedure(after having the previous data, this may be trivial):
(A matrix called A has some values at necessary indexes. I will determine these after some trials.)
Match groups have numeric values, which they retrieve from matrix A.
Group 1 = A(4,2) % 4 words, 2 instances
Group 2 = A(3,3) % 3 words , 3 instances

Then I will assign each text to have a number, which is the sum of numbers of the groups they are inside of.

My problem is forming this dataset in an efficient manner.

Comment: The question/goal is not very clear, but you probably want (an index on) N-grams

Comment: thanks, if you can specify which part was not clear I would try to explain it differently and that may be helpful for me too but N-grams seem cool.

Comment: I read again and changed a bit.

Comment: Please choose a goal. Either you want to find similar texts for a given (new) text, or you want  to cluster *all* the texts.

Comment: I want neither, the goal I want may lead to one of those but essentially what I want is to each text to have some kind of score. I will now write a more detail example which involves texts.

Comment: A score of *what* ?  A score of *uniqueness* would mean: compare all to all. A score wrt a given *phrase* would mean compare 1 to all.

Comment: I tried to explain the definition of the score I meant in the post. I am not so sure but I think I mean compare all to all.

Comment: Do you have some code to share you already developed? Furthermore, in which language do you intend to implement your code in?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I am only thinking about my algorithm right now. I realized what I intend to develop is very much like plagiarism detection softwares and I am now searching about how they work. As language, probably python, but it does not matter that much to me if I need some other language's utility for some reason.

Comment: The difference from plagiarism algorithms and my desired algorithm is that I am searching for substrings which is included in many texts rather than just 2.